Implementing factory that return the correct type
Imagine I have a factory that must create object based on unknown input (let's say user input).
class Base;
class MyFactory {
   static unique_ptr<Base> CreateBase(Input& input);
}

Now this base class may be abstract and have derivation. In some contexts, I want to create the derived object, in others I don't know (nor care) which derivation will be created, as long as I get my Base pointer. So I have adapted method depending on the context:
class Base;
class Foo : public Base;
class Bar : public Base;
class MyFactory {
   static unique_ptr<Foo> CreateFoo(Input& input);
   static unique_ptr<Bar> CreateBar(Input& input);
   static unique_ptr<Base> CreateBase(Input& input);
}

And CreateBase internally tries CreateFoo then CreateBar. Note that failing and returning nullptr is the expected behavior on invalid input.
Let's add another level of derivation :
       Base      
         ▲       
   ┌─────┴────┐  
   │          │  
  Foo        Bar 
   ▲          ▲  
 ┌─┴─┐      ┌─┴─┐
 │   │      │   │
F1  F2     B1  B2

The CreateFoo right now deal with the Input and produce a F1 or a F2 object, and returns it.
But what if two classes like F2 and B1 share some properties that are defined in a interface?
       Base         
         ▲          
   ┌─────┴───────┐  
   │             │  
  Foo           Bar 
   ▲  Interface  ▲  
 ┌─┴─┐    ▲    ┌─┴─┐
 │   │┌───┴───┐│   │
F1   F2       B1  B2

I would like to have a method unique_ptr<Interface> CreateInterface(Input& input); for the contexts where it's an indiferenciate Interface object that I want.
But I can't get my head around how this method could be implemented. The only solution I have is ugly:
unique_ptr<Interface> CreateInterface(Input& input) {
      auto pBase = CreateBase(s);
      std::unique_ptr<Interface> pI = dynamic_pointer_cast<Interface>(pRawI.move());
      return pI;
}

What should be the nice pattern that provides clean CreateBase, CreateFoo, CreateBar and CreateInterface methods?

If it's not a requirement, don't go through CreateBase. Now you basically have two distinct roots to your inheritance graph, so maybe it's better to think about the Base and the Interface types as two distinct starting points. The only possible classes that work here are F2 and B1, so just try F2 first, then B1, and if that fails, return nullptr (the same way you do for Foo & Bar).

This could work as long as Interface is only onF2 and B1. But this is a simplified example: if I have F1...F10 and B1...B10, and multiple interfaces implemented randomly by my 20 classes: then, I will have to copy my full heritage tree into the factory: this seems risky (what I a class gains or loose and interface?) and time consuming

Aside: Not sure why you have class MyFactory instead of namespace MyFactory here.

@Caleth: you're right.

Just stay with one method CreateBase exclusively. In a context which expects a specific type like Foo*, simply convert with dynamic_cast<Foo *> or dynamic_cast<Interface *> to the type you expect (see here how to cast a unique_ptr correctly).
Of course, this will need check for nullptr to make sure Input really produced an object of type Foo or Interface, but that nullptr check will be needed as well when you work with specific methods like CreateFoo or CreateInterface either, so the result will not be very different.
And now you asked "isn't a design that inherently forces me to use dynamic(_pointer)_cast a code smell?" - and the answer is "yes". The cause for that smell is that you have contexts in your program where you call the factory and still need to know which specific derived type you got. Replacing the dynamic(_pointer)_cast by your idea of creating specific sub-factories does not resolve that smell, it just tries to sweep it under the rug.
Let me finally add that sometimes casting down to a specific type is the most pragmatic and simple solution for certain problems, such "code smell" should not be treated as a dogmatic "no-go", but as an opportunity to look twice at the specific code section.

Isn't a design that inherently forces me to use dynamic(_pointer)_cast a code smell?

“Code smell” is a dog whistle.

@sayanel: yes, it may be a code smell, but not because of the cast - see my edit.

the most pragmatic and simple solution for certain problems: Ok I might be overthinking it. I'll just dynamic_cast and move over.

Yet: if I only have the CreateBase, I will always handle and pass around Base* object (assuming construction is only done in the factory). If a function, somewhere, requires an Interface*, then it seems dynamic casting is the only solution then. Is that right?

@sayanel: I doubt it is the only solution, but it is the most simple and straightfoward solution I can come up with. It could also be an opportunity to look at the function which requires the Interface* pointer, why that is the case and why it cannot operate on Base*.

There are two main issues in your design:

the factory needs to know all the possible derivations. This means that if a new derivation is created, your factory needs a rewrite. This is not in line with  (a variant of) the open-closed principle.
trying successively to create all possible derivations somehow feels wrong. A classical variant of the factory is the parametric factory, in which the creation parameter contains a hint of which derivative to create (e.g. parsing a parameter string).

To address these issues you could consider the following:

Not create a factory member function for each possible subtype ("individual factory") in your parametric factory. Instead, stick to one function that always returns a pointer to the base, but with a real object depending on the parameter.
Register the sub-classes that can be instantiated to the global factory, along with a callable that tests the argument before considering the call. This would be used to build dynamically a chain of responsibility pattern to find the suitable class to instantiate. Another possibility would be to considered, e.g. based on some substring, lookup a map. This would be very efficient. In all cases, the benefit is that the registration could be externalised to both the factory and the derivatives, which keeps the design very flexible.
The registration and the test could either use templates (with a template specialisation for the test), or use a free standing factory method (for example a lambda defined at registration).

Edit: some more explanations
To give the spirit of this answer with some (very rudimentary) code, just as a quick and dirty poc:
The factory could look like (I don't like static factories,  but I took it over from your example):
class MyFactory {
public:
   static unique_ptr<Base> createBase(Input& input){
        // first that fires,  returns the element
        for (int i=0; i<test.size(); i++) {
            if (test[i](input)) { 
                cout<<"Rule "<<i<<": ";
                return create[i](input);
            }
        }
        // here,  either create a Base or, if it's abstract or wrong arguments, throw
        cout<<"No rule found: ";
        return make_unique<Base>();
   }

   static void registerDerivate(function<bool(Input&)>t, function<unique_ptr<Base>(Input&)>c){
      test.push_back(t);
      create.push_back(c);
   }
private: 
    static vector<function<bool(Input&)>> test;
    static vector<function<unique_ptr<Base>(Input&)>> create;
};

As you can see, this factor solely depends on Base.  No need to know about derivations. And this is a key in view of the Open/Closed principle.
You would move the identification of the applicable derivatives as well as the rules to apply to chose the right derivative with the right constructor, to the context that knows both Base  and the relevant derivatives:
MyFactory::registerDerivate ([](Input& input){ return input.c=='F' && input.v.size()==1; },
                            [](Input& input) { return make_unique<Foo>(input.v[0]); } );
MyFactory::registerDerivate ([](Input& input){ return input.c=='B' && input.v.size()==1; },
                            [](Input& input) { return make_unique<Bar>(input.s, input.v[0]); } );
MyFactory::registerDerivate ([](Input& input){ return input.c=='B' && input.v.size()!=1; },
                            [](Input& input) { return make_unique<Bar>(input.s, input.v); } );

As you can see, depending on the arguments I could even chose to call different constructors for the same derivation.
Here the full example online.
Some additional ideas:

To be quick I used two separate lambdas,
A cleaner approach could be to use a class that combines the two. This would make especially sense if you don't have a structured input, but if ou need to parse a string to extract the arguments
This version goes sequentially through the rules, because you didn't give much hints about the input. Depending on the case, you could use a map instead of vectors to reduce the applicable rules.  This is important if for example you have complex parsing overhead, and instead of reprising again and again the full string,  you could limit the possibilities with the the help of the first token.


So I only have CreateBase, and it's body should be something like: CreateBase (string Input){ if(input=="F1"){return new F1();} else if(Input=="F2")... ==> Ok. Regarding the Register the sub-classes... part: I don't really see how I could implement this. Could you provide a link or write some pseudo code for example? I particularly don't see how I could "inject" a behavior similar to if(input=="F1"){return new F1();} in the factory without writing this line explicitly (or via some shady macro)

I completed my answer with some code to explain the idea better.  Hope it helps.

Thank you for this complete example! I've never thought of putting the make_unique... in a function stored by the factory. Now all we have to do is ensure all derivation do register, without ever touching the factory. That's neat!

You have three weaknesses.
Your classes should not be aware that they can be created by a factory. Adding them to the factory should cause no change in the class. Instead, you decided they all need a constructor that takes an Input, which likely contains data in a form that the factory understands, but not your classes. Worse if you produce interfaces.
And the only decision that the factory can use is whether a constructor failed or succeeded. I have more often used factories that picked the best out of several suitable classes and constructed it.
And last, your design doesnt allow the factory to be used with different arguments.
I’d have a create method that examines its input to decide which instance to create, and then creates it by calling that classes constructor with the right arguments, possibly adjusting the instance later.

Your classes should not be aware that they can be created by a factory.: they are not. Input is used only by the factory to choose which class to create.

I think this addresses points 2&3 also.
